# Can we add rows to datalist dynamically using a thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

i have a stored procedure which is taking 10 seconds to pull 30 records from a table after long processing.Each datalist item has many controls within which are to be data bound while binding those 30 records to the datalist, which is also taking a bit long.

I want to know if we can assign this job to a thread??

Please help,thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each datalist item has many controls within which are to be data bound
>   while binding those 30 records to the datalist, which is also taking a
>   bit long.

Binding a UI control, shall always be on the UI thread

> I want to know if we can assign this job to a thread?

Simple answer is no for a UI control

Option for you would be an in memory data collection can be updated on a thread, but you need to make it thread safe either using a thread safe collection or a using a construct like `lock`

Final Data binding will always be on UI thread, else it will lead to exception

Comment: thanks for the reply,i could have done it using jquery ajax but there are more data bindings with in the datalist item to handle.can you provide some links on how to acheive this??

Comment: Link for updating in memory collection in parallel mode ? Use any of the suitable collection from System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. A simple multi threading tutorial will provide most of the details